# I want to split the input (input via input box) as string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a situation where I want to have an input box where a string like "C123q23C456a45" is entered. The pattern will remain the same, so it will always be C,3 numbers,A-z,number( this number can be either 2 or 3 digits).
I want to split this string with the C's, so the example above will be split into:
C456a45 and C123q23. this output is showed in a message box in the form of C123 has 23 of q and c456 has 45 of a.
if that makes sense.

how do i approach this?

thanks appreciate it

Comment: hey thanks, that's what i attempted as well. Sorry i didn't mention. It needs to be flexible. eg. have a more than 2 C's so it will return 3 , basically,a(1),a(2) and a(3). How can i accommodate for this flexibility? maybe something that calculates the number of output.. also the number after the alphabet could be 3 or 4 digit as well...not always 2.

Comment: thanks and sorry i didnt mention it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live without VBA to do this, you can use these formulas if you have the string you want to split in `A1`:

`=LEFT(A1;FIND("C";A1;FIND("C";A1)+2)-1)` for `C123q23`
`=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-LEN(LEFT(A1;FIND("C";A1;FIND("C";A1)+2)-1)))` for `C456a45`

** UPDATED **

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim strFirstSplitA As String, str1A As String, str2A As String
Dim strA As String, strAA As String, strAAA As String
Dim str1B As String, strB As String, strBB As String, strBBB As String
Dim strMsgBoxA As String, strMsgBoxB As String

str1A = InStr(1, Range("A1"), "C") + 2
str2A = InStr(str1A, Range("A1"), "C")                              '                           FIND("C";A1)+2)-1)
strFirstSplitA = Left(Range("A1"), str2A - 1)

strA = Left(strFirstSplitA, 4)
strAA = Right(strFirstSplitA, Len(strFirstSplitA) - 4)
strAAA = Right(strAA, Len(strAA) - Len(Left(strAA, 1)))
strMsgBoxA = strA & " has " & strAAA & " of " & Left(strAA, 1)
' C123 has 23 of q

str1B = Right(Range("A1"), Len(Range("A1")) - Len(strFirstSplitA))

strB = Left(str1B, 4)
strBB = Right(str1B, Len(str1B) - 4)
strBBB = Right(strBB, Len(strBB) - Len(Left(strBB, 1)))
strMsgBoxB = strB & " has " & strBBB & " of " & Left(strBB, 1)
' c456 has 45 of a

MsgBox strMsgBoxA & " and " & strMsgBoxB

End Sub
```

Comment: hey thanks buddy but unfortunately i do need vba. appreciate your time!

Comment: Glad it works. A bit messy, but I guess you can change the names yourself  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but something like this:

```
a = Split("C123q23C456a45", "C")

For i = 1 To Ubound(a)
    Debug.Print Left$(a(i), 3), Mid$(a(i), 5)
Next
```

Comment: hey cheers man it does work but for this question niclas had been more accurate. Thanks!